# Как создать службу в Windows Mobile на управляемом коде?

Tags: windows, .net

В обычном Windows (не Mobile) служба создается без особых проблем с помощью стандартного шаблона (Windows Service) Visual Studio. Но подобного шаблона, равно как и упоминаний на MSDN о создании служб средствами .NET для Windows Mobile нет.

Есть ли способ?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите здесь: [Managed Services for Windows Mobile](http://managedserviceswm.codeplex.com/).

> Эта легковесная библиотека содержит функции для создания приложений Windows в управляемом коде подобных службам.